# Error while setting Auto layout constraint for UITableView and UILabel

Tags: uitableview, ios6, autolayout, visual-format-language

There is a UITableView created programmatically and a UILabel created in interface builder. I want to set auto layout constraint so that the table always appears below the label keeping a fixed distance.Here is my code :

```
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 100.0, 312.0, 103.0)    style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;        
    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    tableView.rowHeight = 40;
    [tableView reloadData];
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];


    //Trying to put the table under a label named labelMembersLogin
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                           @"V:|-[labelMembersLogin]-[tableView(==100)]"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.labelMembersLogin,tableView)]];
```

But the program crashes when I run it.Its the first view Controller of my app.

Comment: You can't use initWithFrame in autolayout. You should add constraints for size and position.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you lead me to any good tutorial on autolayout ?

Comment: Some useful Links for you -      http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2 and http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/